# 8 copies of td item while looping while using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, loops, nokogiri

I can't for the life of me see why I get 8 of the particular value (td[0]) every time it loops. I checked against what I saw online, but obviously I'm wrong.

Assume 'table' is related to some Nokogiri html path. I'm trying to get the contents of the first td (position 0, so td[0]) inside a tr.

```
result = []
table.search('tr').map do |row|
  row.search('td').each do |td|

    result.push(row.search('td')[0].text.to_s)

 end
end

puts result
```

I just want the data at position[0] from each tr once. Instead, I'm getting 8 copies of td[0] for each tr. I'm missing something obvious I think, but what?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]". When asking about this sort of question, we need the minimal input data (HTML) necessary to demonstrate the problem, along with the expected output. Without that we have to try to figure out what the input should look like, which wastes our time and yours, and if the input turns out to be wrong and we can't check the output against yours, then the answer is wrong. Also, please read the help for formatting your text. Properly formatted text makes it much easier for us to understand what you're saying.

Answer (score -1):

```
result = []
table.css('tr').each do |row|
  result << row.css('td')[0].text if row.css('td')[0]
end
```

The problem was very simple, some rows may not have td at all. That's why you want to check if there is any td, before you call #text.

If you prefer using #map:

```
result = table.css('tr').map do |row| # map returns array of results
  row.css('td')[0].text if row.css('td')[0]
end.compact # compact deletes all the nil elements from array
```

Comment: Hey Diodon. Thanks for the response! I tried that, but I get a undefined method text for nil:NilClass. You're right. I should be able to take just the mapped rows, and assign a position, but no dice.

Comment: Hey. I'll check it out, but I checked the rows and they all have tds. I'll update you.

Comment: The question and answer are missing context which would help make them both usable for others. It's important to understand that SO isn't a "help _me_" site, it's a "here's a question other's will have, along with me, and here is the solution or solutions that fix it" site. So the context (input HTML) is extremely important. Inside knowledge of the problem short-circuits the usefulness for others unless you show the whole situation.

Comment: `row.css('td')[0]` is better written `row.at('td')`. Using an `if` inside a `map` forces you to use `compact` afterwards because it'll generate nil elements. Instead use a more comprehensive `table.css('tr')` statement, probably with a `reject` or `select` to find the `td` elements you want. Then you can remove the `if` clause along with `compact`. Filter it first correctly and you won't have to clean up the mess later.